# How can I do array to assign another array and trim?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, trim

I have textarea and textare jsccode as the following :

```
var checkName = (document.getElementById("List").value);
var tempcheckNames = checkName.split('\n');
```

and assign array another array with trim.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tempcheckNames.length;i++){
    checkNames = tempcheckNames[i].trim().split('\n');
}
```

But checkNames is empty because assign with not array ?

So I want to trim from textarea value (I did textarea value split so my array is  textarea value ('\n')

Comment: Should `checkNames` be a string, an array, or an array of arrays?

Comment: should be array @guest271314

Comment: Just try `checkName.split('\n').map(function(item){ return item.trim(); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way, that's shorter

```
var checkName = document.getElementById("List").value.split("\n").map(element => element.trim());
```

Comment: Yeap. that's it !!

Answer (score 1):

Define `checkNames` as an array, use `.push()` to add items to `checkNames` array within `for` loop, remove call to `.split()` within `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0, checkNames = [] /* define `checkNames` as an array */
    ; i < tempcheckNames.length
    ; i++) {
    checkNames.push(tempcheckNames[i].trim()); 
    // .split('\n'); `.split()` not needed here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @guest271314

Answer (score 1):

You can push the values to an array to get all the split values

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-show');
btn.addEventListener('click', btnShow);

function btnShow (e) {
  var checkName = (document.getElementById("list").value);
  var tempcheckNames = checkName.split('\n');
  var checkNames = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < tempcheckNames.length;i++){
    checkNames.push(tempcheckNames[i].trim());
  }
  alert(checkNames);
}
```

```html
<textarea id='list'> </textarea>

<button id='btn-show'>Show</button>
```

**Functional approach using Array.map**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-show');
btn.addEventListener('click', btnShow);

function btnShow (e) {
  var checkName = (document.getElementById("list").value);

  const checkNames = checkName.split('\n').map((name) => name.trim() );
  
  alert(checkNames);
}
```

```html
    <textarea id='list'> </textarea>

    <button id='btn-show'>Show</button>
```

Comment: What is purpose of calling `.split('\n')` within `for` loop?

Comment: than you very much.